# Trying to get table rows equal height in table layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablelayout

I am using a TableLayout where each table row will consist of three cells which will each display an image. I want each imageview/cell to be of equal height and width. The problem is, the tablerow height by default wraps to the size of the imageview/cell with the largest height, so the rows are not equal height.

```
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(tableLayout.getWidth()/3, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.3f);
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            lp.setMargins(1,1,1,1);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(lp);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            tableRow.addView(imageView);
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

Here is the xml

```
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:weightSum="1"
                app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1">
            </TableLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like currently
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use 2 way for fix your problem

One:

set something like this code in your xml

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1">
        </TableLayout>
```

in this way you say to your layout that use the width and height that you want like Instagram.

Two:
send same size images to your app or resize it to what you want

i prefer both ways together.

Update me in comments

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of hardcoding the width and height like that. I prefer it to be dynamic so it can adapt to various screen sizes and aspect ratios, I think I might try and resize it.

Comment: resize may cause your image go aggrieve and not good, just try it and double check

Comment: ended up hard coding the TableLayout params height to 300dp, seems to work nicely across phone devices.

Comment: Glad to hear that .